# How to solve: Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate

Tags: ios, xcode

My Parent app IS signed correctly. I have verified in every screen. Has anyone seen this?

It's complaining about my watchKit app.

Thanks!

### XCode 10.0 beta 6

```
error: Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app. Verify the embedded binary target's code sign settings match the parent app's.

  Embedded Binary Signing Certificate: Software Signing
  Parent App Signing Certificate: - (Ad Hoc Code Signed)
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with the signing. The answer for me was to paste $(ARCHS_STANDARD) into the project valid architecture field. Incredible!

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That fixed for me as well.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! THIS is why I hate this stuff. Instead of using my time to code I have to fix these damn signing issues.

Comment: Thumbs up! We've to do this in the embeded binary's Build Settings, which is Watch App in my case.

Comment: Amazing.....i was stuck on this problem for many days....... now problem solved, thanks so much for give this unique tricks.

Comment: This solved my problem. Xcode stupidly threw me on a wild goose chase about provisioning profiles and signing certs and all that when it was really the architectures getting incorrectly set that was causing problems. fml

Comment: This answer guide me to fix the error. So I'm matching all value of **Build Active Architecture Only** and **Excluded Architectures**, my main app setting to Notification Service.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with XCode 12 after adding a widget extension. However all my architectures settings were already set to $(ARCHS_STANDARD).

It turns out that this signing error was **spurious** and was apparently a side-effect of my having added an undefined symbol in a code module I had added into the widget extension. After removing that code module from the extension it built without any signing error, again.

Comment: You should earn a medal 

Answer (score 1):

For me I had an embedded App Clip that was targeting iOS 15 and the iOS app was targeting iOS 16. Switching the App Clip to iOS 16 did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Had same error in Xcode 12 running on M1 after deleting my

~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

as part of clean build.  Tried everything above, nothing helped.

Decided to change the Xcode project type from Xcode "12.0-compatible" to "Xcode 8.0-compatible" and then the project started building correctly (again).